# Click Text on Recyclerview to expand

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I have a Recyclerview that works like the instagram UI. I want to set an onclick listener to the text below the image so that it expands when clicked and collapse when clicked again JUST like the Instagram app. below is how it looks like.

[image: Cardview]

So when the "lorem ipsum" text is clicked, it should expand and show the rest of the text. when clicked again, it should collapse.

This is how i wrote the TextView in my CardView.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mCardDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
        aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation"
         />
```

Really need help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: add some more code, what are you doing atm ? isn't a simple visibility change going to help you?

Comment: currently i havent added any onclick listener because i don't know how to go about it since Recyclerview by default does not come with onItemClick Listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your onBindViewHolder you can set up the click listener for that particular text view which you want to expand or collapse. In the below code rh is your row holder object, expandable is your boolean value to check if currently text is expanded or not. Do let me know if you have any issues.

```
onBindViewHolde(....){
rh.readMoreTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (!rh.expandable) {
                            rh.expandable = true;
                            rh.readMoreTxt.setText("Show less");
                        } else {
                            rh.expandable = false;

                            rh.readMoreTxt.setText("Show more");
                        }
                    }
                });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve your problem.

```
private boolean isVisible;

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    isVisible = !isVisible;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isVisible) {
            //Make VISIBLE visibility of your view
            } else {
            //Make GONE visibility of your view
            }
    });
```

Comment: this code sets the visiblity for the textview at all positions. i want to be able to expand the textview for only the clicked position